# Understanding multiple @ symbols in DNS settings

Tags: dns, ip-address

I don't understand how multiple @ symbols work in the DNS settings, and what will happen when I edit the associated records.

The screenshot below is what is set up already for a website I'm working on.

1. If I change the value (166.78.44.155) of the first A record which is named @, will it affect any of the other records below it that are set as @? In other words, if I change the IP address in the first A record, will the MX, NS, SOA, and TXT records below change how things are working / break things?
2. If I need to change the IP address of the first record, and IF it will affect the other records, what would be the correct names and values to set the other records to in order to keep them functioning as they are now?

Thank you

[image: DNS Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

> I don't understand how multiple @ symbols work in the DNS settings

Absolutely like any other kind of resource record, there is nothing special about this, it is a shortcut to the zone itself.

For the zone `example.com`, this:

```
@ IN MX 10 mx1.example.com.
@ IN MX 20 mx2.example.com.
@ IN A 192.0.2.137
@ IN A 192.0.2.201
@ IN AAAA 2001:DB8::ABCD
@ IN AAAA 2001:DB8::1
```

is **exactly** the same as:

```
example.com. IN MX 10 mx1.example.com.
example.com. IN MX 20 mx2.example.com.
example.com. IN A 192.0.2.137
example.com. IN A 192.0.2.201
example.com. IN AAAA 2001:DB8::ABCD
example.com. IN AAAA 2001:DB8::1
```

So for the explanation of what happens when multiple records for same label, it is exactly the same: resource records are **sets** (and not lists, as there is no order), so each relevant record is returned for a given query on a type.

Using `@` is just a shortcut when **writing** the zonefile. It has no impact on how the DNS messages are exchanged, and does not appear in packets.

And to go back to your question, each element of the set is independant of the other, so you change change one without impact to the other (they will still be replied together for the relevant query).
Special rules apply of course when you change or add a new resource **type** such as a `CNAME` that has specific constraints.

You can change the IP address of your `@ A` record it will impact only resolutions of your zone name as label (because `@` is your zone name), it will not impact resolution of `pairings` label or other ones (except if they are `CNAME` records towards the zone name of course, in which case the change in the `A` record will apply to all of them, as it is the exact purpose of a `CNAME` record).

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on CNAME a bit more? The situation I have per the screenshot is that the CNAME value (blurred out) is some old / irrelevant domain name I don't believe the client is using. The new website is a wpengine blog at [domainname].wpengine.com (we want the blog to be at domainname.com and not show the .wpengine.com URL in the browser). Can I change the CNAME value to that wpengine URL? How will the A record with an IP address and the CNAME with the wpengine URL affect each other? Would that be an incorrect setup? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `A` record for `@` to your new server's IP address. What this will do is point your website `example.com` to the new server.

You may also want to create a new `www` `A` record to point the WWW version of your website (`www.example.com`) [if not already automatically pointed with the standalone @].

You can change `pairings` which a subdomain (`pairings.example.com`) to the new IP address **if needed** too.

As for the `MX` (used for email settings), `CNAME` and `TXT` records, these will remain as per their current settings. I'm not aware of what `SOA` does, so hopefully, someone can help you with this.

As for the `NS` which stands for `Name Server`, there are normally two records. Changing these will point the whole `DNS` (all the records) to the new host [of which the `NS` is assigned to]. **You shouldn't change** this unless you're planning to carry across all the current records to your new host too. As if you don't, these records would no-longer function.

Comment: The screenshot already shows a `CNAME` for `www`, so creating an `A` record for the same label is not possible (or the `CNAME` should be removed first).

Comment: `SOA` is basically the only mandatory record in a zone, with `NS` ones (they can be more than 2 , this is ok), it stands for `Start Of Authority` and basically just says that indeed this current "zonefile" is the authoritative content for this zone. It provides various values needed for DNS operations, and should really not be changed without first really understanding its use and consequences.

Answer (score 3):

In this case the `@` symbol means the domain apex.   That is: the domain name with no subdomain.

So if your domain is `example.com`:

- `@` → `example.com`
- `www` → `www.example.com`
- `drive` → `drive.example.com`

If you edit the `A` record associated with the `@`, it will change where your bare domain points.   The A record for the domain apex usually points to the same IP address as `www`.   You could have separate servers handling the two if you really wanted to.   One use case for that would be having the domain apex point to a redirect service that redirects the HTTP requests to `www.example.com` while having a different server that serves the main content for your domain on the `www` subdomain.

Note that a `CNAME` record should not be associated with the domain apex.  You should always use an `A` record there.   A `CNAME` with `@` isn't allowed by the DNS spec although some DNS servers won't complain if you try it.  If you end up with a `CNAME` at the apex, it causes MX records to be ignored and email to be misdelivered.

`MX`, `NS`, `SOA`, and `TXT` records are almost always associated with domain apex.  It wouldn't usually make sense to have anything other than the `@` with them.  Those records are "special" records that don't resolve  HTTP or other socket level protocols to IP addresses.   `MX` records are for specifying email servers.   `NS` records are for specifying domain name servers.  `SOA` records are for specifying DNS authority.   `TXT` records are more generic and mostly used for verification records.

Comment: _Aside:_The unicode character you've used in your list ( - which appears to be "U+1F806: RIGHTWARDS ARROW WITH MEDIUM TRIANGLE ARROWHEAD"?) doesn't display on any of my devices (Windows 7 desktop, iOS or Android)?

Comment: *A CNAME with @ isn't defined well* it is against the DNS protocol specification, and while some provider propose the same feature, named in various ways (ALIAS, ANAME, etc.), a standard DNS server will refuse by default to load a zone with `@ CNAME` in it.

Comment: @MrWhite I edited in a different arrow.   Every single arrow on this page renders for me on Linux:  http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html  I had no idea unicode symbol support was so spotty.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Some DNS servers can be wrongly configured to use a CNAME at the apex. Users can access your website, but mail breaks.    I'm sure some DNS servers refuse the records entirely, but I haven't experienced that.   ServerFault has an answer that explains the spec.  It isn't that it forbids a CNAME there, it is that it forbids CNAME with other records types and requires other records at the apex.  [Why can't a CNAME record be used at the apex (aka root) of a domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain)

Comment: Yes a CNAME is forbidden anywhere there is another record type for same label, which is always the case at apex because of SOA and NS records, and may be the case also elsewhere depending on what other labels are already there. (I am quite aware of the spec, as it is my day job since 20 years).

Comment: As for nameservers and loading zones, see for example: https://deepthought.isc.org/article/AA-01640/0/CNAME-at-the-apex-of-a-zone.html. *ISC BIND will therefore not allow you to add a CNAME at the zone apex because this will create a broken zone and cause DNS resolution failures.  The interpretation of the CNAME record (per the DNS protocol) makes it nonsensical to have a CNAME coexisting with any other records for that same name.* and the later part in green box. So CNAME at apex is fully defined and is: not allowed.

Comment: While certainly not as elegant, but to improve interoperability, '->' would have conveyed the same semantic as any fancy Unicode arrow character ;-) But now I can at least read yours, which was not the case before.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The DNS article you linked to has a "WARNING: 'Clever' provisioning servers" section that describes what happens if you try to put a CNAME in the APEX.   It says that mail breaks, which is what I have experienced when I've tried it.

Comment: Yes, but read it fully, up to last sentence: *Other services that are dependent on reliable DNS resolution will also experience intermittent failures.* and in the middle: *It is not a good solution because resolvers (following the DNS protocol correctly) cache what they have learned.* So it is worthless to do. Also there are not only A/AAAA/MX records to care about. You observe a problem with A/MX because this is what you try, but you would have problems in the same way for SRV, TXT, etc... any type. And imagine the problems with NS ones...

Comment: And also again, try it if you do not believe me: bind for example will **refuse** to load the zonefile if it has CNAME at apex. Other nameservers will probably do the same thing. Of course DNS providers are free to run their own DNS servers that do differently.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Only about 60-70% of those "arrows" appear on my Windows 7 machine. _About_ the same on my iPad (iOS 11.4) - although the styling of some of the arrows on iOS is very different. My Android 7.0 phone displays only about 50%. (The arrow you changed it to works OK on all.)